# trying to print out the array in java

Tags: java, stringtokenizer, nosuchelementexception

```
System.out.println("Please input the elements and seperate each by a  comma.");
e = dk.nextLine();
String[] elems = new String[e.length()];
st = new StringTokenizer(e,",");

for (int i = 0; i<e.length(); i++) {
   elems[i] = st.nextToken().toString();
}

for (int i=0; i<e.length(); i++){
   System.out.println(elems[i]);
}
```

I am trying to print out the array `elems[]` but it wont work the error `java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349` seems to be at line:

> elems[i] = st.nextToken().toString();

can you help me identify and understand the problem?

Comment: And this error is...?

Comment: Did you get something like `java.lang.FooException at foo.bar.baz() at bar.foobar() at foo.bar.qux()`?

Comment: For starters, initialize the array (`elems`) with `st.countTokens()` instead of `e.length()`. `st.nextToken().toString()` is redundant, use `st.nextToken()` instead. The loops also have to be changed accordingly.

Comment: The error is Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
@MarcB @ dorukayhan

Comment: The problem is that there are fewer tokens in `e` than the length of `e`: think about `"Hello,World"`: 2 tokens (`Hello` and `World`), but the length is 11. You run out of things to read.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A correct version:

```
String[] elems = e.split(",");
for(String elem : elems) {
    System.out.println(elem);
}
```

---

The mistake you made is that `e.length()` returns the size of the `string` (its number of characters) so you ended up calling `st.nextToken()` more times than there are actual tokens separated by `","`. Hence the exception.

Comment: ill try it out thanks and if you dont mind can you tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@Jean posted a slim version of what you are trying, but ultimately to help to understand the error

```
e = dk.nextLine(); // input: Alfredo,Bauer,Cisco
String[] elems = new String[e.length()]; // length is 20 
st = new StringTokenizer(e,","); // st has a length of 3
```

Now if you call it like this

```
for(int i = 0;i<e.length();i++){
elems[i] = st.nextToken().toString(); // NoSuchElementException
}
```

Because you try to call the [nextToken()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextToken()) which does not exist.

The docs:

> Returns the next token from this string tokenizer.
>   Throws:
>   NoSuchElementException - if there are no more tokens in this
>   tokenizer's string.

To fix your problem use the length of [countTokens()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#countTokens())

OR

```
while(st.hasMoreElements()){
  elems[i] = st.nextToken().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative.

```
    String[] elems = e.split(",");

    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(elems ));
```